# Preserving formatting of Scales & Legends in Templates

Tags: qgis, print-composer

My QGIS templates don't seem to preserve the formatting of my scales or legends. Is there a way to save these so they don't have to be redone each time? (I'm doing a series of maps that will be the same scale and have the same legends.)
Thanks
TVZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens here in 1.8. Print composer templates work as they should in the current Master (Ubuntu). N.

Comment: I'm sorry, nhopton, I need to have things spelled out. Are you saying that QGIS Version 1.8 is not the most current, or best? If so, how should I update mine?
Thanks.

Comment: The current development version of QGIS (1.9.x) is called 'Master'. If you wanted to, you could install this using OSGeo4W or from one of the links on the QGIS download page. But just at present there are problems with Master and some of its functions don't work properly. I have to use Master for its print composer, but I couldn't recommend it to anyone else as it stands today.

Answer (score 2):

[image]What i tend to do i create a different project for each client.

Create a new print composer.

Load from templates. (presume you have already made a template and all your text boxes will be the same).

Create new print composer for each map and simple copy and paste legend across to the next.

Before closing, open composer manager and rename each composer to what you want. you can then open and switch between each.

If you save project and dont close the composer window it will open again where you left it at the save.

So basically do templates and work from there.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. However, I must be missing something silly. I can't see how I copy or paste items in a print composer!

Comment: Sorry I should have said. Just Select it with the select tool (I will add the image above if i can) then use the keyboard shortcuts. For copy ctrl+c and for paste ctrl+v.